# Overwrite source variable with .split() result

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

Is there any trouble splitting variables that were previously split and overwrite the original variable while doing so?

Example:

```
arr = str.split(" ");
arr = arr[0].split("/");
```

I tested it and it works. But:

- Is it risky to do this?
- Will it behave as I expect at all times, and on all browsers?

Comment: I'd modify it to something like `arr = str.split(' '); arr = arr ? arr[0].split('/') : ''` unless you want it to error out if splitting on a space returns 0 results.

Comment: I have a habit of doing this in certain cases, so that I don't have to create a bunch of variables that are only transitory. I don't see any problem with doing it, and it will work on all browsers.

Comment: Its fine as long as arr has > 0 elements.

Comment: @Munim, @JesseB - the `.split()` method always returns a non-empty array, even if the source string was empty or didn't contain the separator.

Comment: @Jared Farrish, your website is 'interesting'... hehe

Comment: @nnnnnn have you tried to split a string like this? `"".split('')`

Comment: @Munim - you're right, that returns an empty array (at least in IE). But `"".split(" ")` returns a one-element array so the code in the question will be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will be fine in all browsers. There's no risk.

You are simply assigning the variable `arr` to refer to something new, it doesn't matter what it used to refer to. (This doesn't actually "overwrite the older array", but if there are no other references to the old array the garbage collector will take care of it.)

You can also do it in one line:

```
arr=str.split(" ")[0].split("/");
```

Note that [according to MDN, `.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) always returns an array with at least one element, even if the source string was empty or didn't contain the separator.

EDIT: If both source string *and* separator are empty strings `.split()` seems to return an empty array. I.e., `"".split("")` returns `[]`. Thanks Munim for pointing that out. (But `"".split(" ")` returns `[""]` so there will be no problem for purposes of this question.)

Answer (score 0):

not risky at all if you know that arr is getting totally overwritten.  It may be bad practice to do this for larger pieces of code or if other people are going to read it but there's nothing wrong with this logic-wise.
if you want to get more cryptic, try this:
arr=str.split(" ")[0].split("/");

of course you have to make sure that all the various pieces evaluate (if for instance, you have no spaces, then the [0] will be null and you'll get an error.
if you know that you ALWAYS have a space in str then this will be the hardest to read version of the code above ;)